# How do i get data from a textbox that is made during the runtime of the program?

Tags: vb.net

this is my code its the start of a customer details editing system for my course work

```
Public Class editCustomerFields
    Dim textbox As New TextBox
    Private Sub editCustomerFields_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim updownLBL As Integer = 55
        Dim updownTXT As Integer = 80
        Dim leftRight As Integer = 30
        For i = 0 To globalVariables.countForCustomerDetails - 1
            Dim label As New Label


            label.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(159, 23)
            label.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(leftRight, updownLBL)
            label.Text = globalVariables.fieldsCustomerDetailsArray(globalVariables.editCustomerDetailsTxtNamesList.Item(i))
            label.Name = globalVariables.fieldsCustomerDetailsArray(globalVariables.editCustomerDetailsTxtNamesList.Item(i))
            Me.Controls.Add(label)

            TextBox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(315, 30)
            TextBox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(leftRight, updownTXT)
            textbox.Name = globalVariables.fieldsCustomerDetailsArray(globalVariables.editCustomerDetailsTxtNamesList.Item(i))
            MsgBox(TextBox.Name)
            Me.Controls.Add(textbox)

            globalVariables.txtEditCustomerDetailsArray(i) = textbox.Name


            updownLBL += 60
            updownTXT += 60

            If updownTXT >= 500 Then
                leftRight = 350
                updownTXT = 80
                updownLBL = 55
            End If
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

i have a bunch of checkboxes that the user selects that correspond to the different fields in the database. then the program takes the input and on another form displays textboxes and labels for the user to enter data into. How do I get the data entered in the textbox?

`fieldsCustomerDetailsArray` is an array of the field names ("username","password" etc)

`editCustomerDetailsTxtNamesList` is a list of the checkboxes for the array to use

Comment: Change `Dim textbox` to `Public textbox`.  Now you can access it from the instance of `editCustomerFields` that you created (whatever that is named). For instance, if you did `Dim edit As New editCustomerFields()`, then you can use `edit.textbox.Text` to get the value from the TextBox in that specific instance of the form (assuming you actually displayed it to the user at some point).

Comment: But...WHY are you "designing" the controls in code like this in the first place?